# How can I calculate the standard error of the poisson.test in R?

Tags: r

I have such a dataset,

```
ID   Freq.x Freq.y
 1      1    8
 2      5    3
        ...
```

I calculated the ratio between two rate parameters of Freq.x and Freq.y by using R-programming language poisson.test function, but I want to calculate the standard error. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any reproducible data in your question, so let's make some:

```r
set.seed(69)

x <- rpois(100, lambda = 7)
y <- rpois(100, lambda = 8)
```

You can get the standard error for each of these two *variables* like this:

```r
se_x <- sqrt(mean(x)) / length(x)
se_y <- sqrt(mean(y)) / length(y)

se_x
#> [1] 0.02638181

se_y
#> [1] 0.02840775
```

and you can compare the two to determine if the underlying rate is significantly different like this:

```
poisson.test(c(sum(x), sum(y)))
#> 
#>  Comparison of Poisson rates
#> 
#> data:  c(sum(x), sum(y)) time base: 1
#> count1 = 696, expected count1 = 751.5, p-value = 0.004533
#> alternative hypothesis: true rate ratio is not equal to 1
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  0.7781748 0.9556714
#> sample estimates:
#> rate ratio 
#>  0.8624535
```

It's not clear what you mean by the standard error of the `poisson.test` though.

Comment: Yes, this is true to compare the ratio between two rate parameters, but what is the standard error of this `poisson.test(c(sum(x), sum(y)))` .hereby we have CI, so we would have the standard error, but I couldn't see it in the output.

Comment: The standard error is useful when the distribution is normal, but not so much when it is Poisson which is an asymmetrical distribution. Look at the difference between .862... and the upper and lower bound of the confidence interval. They are not the same (.084 vs .093). You could approximate a standard error by adding these together and dividing by 2 * 1.96 approximately 0.045.